# Can't mange to get proxypass working with apache to gerrit

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, gerrit

don't worry about the Ip and user those are just for tests, this server will be destroyed when I'm done.

I'm on debian 9 with apache 2.4.25n this is a remote server, I'm tring to access it from the internet

So I installed gerrit, got it running and put this in his conf file (`~/gerrit_server/etc/gerrit.config`) :

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        canonicalWebUrl = http://95.179.219.75:8087/
        serverId = bd679dac-5adf-47c8-b665-84a3ab90ecaa
[container]
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.backend_factory=com.google.common.flogger.backend.log4j.Log4jBackendFactory#getInstance"
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.logging_context=com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContext#getInstance"
        user = root
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
[index]
        type = lucene
[auth]
        type = HTTP
[receive]
        enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:8087/gerrit/
[cache]
        directory = cache
[database]
        type = h2
        database = /home/magicmike/gerrit_server/db/ReviewDB
```

Using `http://95.179.219.75:8087/gerrit` works

Then I added this file : `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gerrit`
And wrote this inside

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName 95.179.219.75

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
    # Use following line instead of the previous two on Apache >= 2.4
    # Require all granted
  </Proxy>

  AllowEncodedSlashes On
  ProxyPass /gerrit/ http://127.0.0.1:8087/gerrit/ nocanon
</VirtualHost>
```

then I added a simlink to sites-enabled
`sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/gerrit.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gerrit.conf`

and restarted apache : `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Going to `http://95.179.219.75/gerrit` display : 404 error

I also tried with `listenUrl = proxy-http://*:8087/gerrit/` in gerrit's conf it changes nothing (I of course restarted gerrit and apache after that change)

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

## EDIT

From the apache logs :

[Thu Feb 20 17:21:39.314275 2020] [core:info] [pid 30994:tid 139939108706048] [client 163.62.112.77:16341] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/gerrit

Why would it want something from /var/www/html/gerrit?

Answer (score 0):

http://95.179.219.75/gerrit/ had to be used not http://95.179.219.75/gerrit (missing '/' at the end)